# How to retrieve particular data from a group of data by specifying one of them in textview in android studio via firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to retrieve data by specifying its sibling's data in textview ,please someone help me how to deal with it , the code and JSON tree is provided below.
i have retrieve  by directly specifying the path of data which is applicable for single retrieval for multiple sets of data i'm getting failed ,i had tried to pass TextView to stingview and called it at path in which i'm failing too.

```
public class smartphone extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button fetch,accept;
    TextView content;
    EditText one,two;
    DatabaseReference rootRef,demoRef;
    LinearLayout layout1,layout2;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smartphone);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Smartphone details");
        final LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fetch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.fetchDocument);
    fetch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    accept=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    content=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    one=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.two);
    String brand="";
    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    demoRef = rootRef.child("mobile/samsung/j7/");
    demoref1=demoRef.getRoot().equalTo(one.getText().toString());
    fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = one.getText().toString().trim();
            String model = two.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&&TextUtils.isEmpty(model)) {
                Toast.makeText(smartphone.this, "Please Enter Make and Model", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            demoRef.child("price").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            //demoref1.orderByChild("price").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    content.setText(value);
                    fetch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }  
            });
        }
    });
    accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), location.class));
        }
    });
}
```

}

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV6Mw.png)

Comment: Please post database structure and which data you want to retrieve

Comment: Please specify clearly what do you want by providing what?

Comment: actually, i want to retrieve a price amount of a product , so i am giving the value of 2 strings as input i.e brand name and its series name.

Comment: I want a string variable to work as a path which references the values I give in textview. someone please help me how to get out of this problem.